# Save,Update and delete page. Saving duplicated data

Tags: c#, sql

I was watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJ-RyDl5E7U  It basically teaches me how to create my update and delete button after following the video my program works just like his!

But there is no "checking" statement for my btnSave, allowing the user to enter duplicated data in the data base if they click more than once shown here
[image: Duplicated data shown in the SQL database]
So I was wondering if there is a "checking statement" I can use, like if the IndexNumber (first column) exist there will be a message box showing out saying something like "ID is already exists"

This is my current code for the btnSave

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO GlennTeoStudents (IndexNumber,Name,Age,HandphoneNumber,GPA) VALUES ('" + numIN.Value + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtAge.Text + "','" + txtHP.Text + "','" + numGPA.Value + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Disable the Save button on click and enable it after the Save process is completed and the grid is refreshed... And to avoid duplication, add integrity constraints in your underlying database table...

Comment: I agree with Saagar that you should add a DB level unique index as the last line of defense. You should also try to catch this in logic before it hits the DB as in Insert. If it tries to insert and fails because of a unique index you will need some exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using ado.net something like this;

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=" + "Application.StartupPath" + "\\GlennTeoDB.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
con.Open();

//get a count records with your index number
SqlCommand validate = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT count(IndexNumber) FROM GlennTeoStudents WHERE IndexNumber = {0}", numIN.Value), con);
int count = (Int32)validate.ExecuteScalar();

if (count == 0)
{
    //insert your unqiue index number into a new row
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO GlennTeoStudents (IndexNumber,Name,Age,HandphoneNumber,GPA) VALUES ('" + numIN.Value + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtAge.Text + "','" + txtHP.Text + "','" + numGPA.Value + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();               
}
else
{
    //don't insert it, do something else like return an error
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: Ado.net? I am just doing a simple project using C# windor form application. Thanks for your answer! I'll try it soon

Comment: Yes you are using ado.net. The example you provided uses an ado.net data provider, System.Data.SqlClient.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Darren, thanks for you help but your code does not work. I am still able to spam the save button and save duplicated data. I have edited your else code to show a message box but

Comment: Can you confirm if the count is working? Try stepping through your code and checking the value of the count.

Comment: Does it affect the code if I already have 5 rows of data already in the database?

Comment: Assuming VisualStudio, add a breakpoint and start debugging (F5). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kya29xtx.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I added a break point (F9) to " if (count == 0)" and ran it. When I clicked "btnSave' nothing happene and nothing is being shown.

Comment: Place the breakpoint on the line of code above that,  int count = (Int32)validate.ExecuteScalar();

Once you start debugging it should catch on your breakpoint (turn yellow), step over (F10) to the next line of code, you should then be able to hover over the count and see the value (or open the window under Debug > Windows > Locals to see the local variables while your debugging).

Comment: Okay,now I have this error "{"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file Application.StartupPath\\GlennTeoDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."} " But I am still able to save data to my data base

Comment: After editing the sqlconnection line, I get this error "{"Invalid column name 'count'."}"

Comment: But in your code, you have already declare "count" as int? In my database there is no "count"

Comment: It will be difficult to help you further unless you post some more code in your question. At least all of the btnSave function.

Comment: Ah sorry that's my bad SQL, try my revised answer. Count(IndexNumber)

Comment: My entire code of btnSave is in my very first post of this thread. I would like to thank you for your help so far. What do I replace with Count(IndexNumber)? Do you mind writing the full code?

Comment: I updated my answer above, its the SELECT. It should be  SELECT COUNT(IndexNumber) FROM ... rather than... SELECT COUNT IndexNumber FROM

Comment: Yup great!, It's working fine, thank you Darren S for your patience. I have upvote and marked it as answer. Have a nice day! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You should add an existence check:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO GlennTeoStudents (IndexNumber,Name,Age,HandphoneNumber,GPA) VALUES ('" + numIN.Value +
    "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtAge.Text + "','" + txtHP.Text +
    "','" + numGPA.Value + "') WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM
    GlennTeoStudents WHERE IndexNumber = '" + numIN.Value + "')", con);
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your code and arrange it into a line but I got an error "Error 1 The name 'con' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: How did you try it? Con is the SQL connection you are creating. Its the same code as yours just with the existence check.

Comment: I basically copy and paste your code and arrange it in a line. Yup, I do not understand why I will have an error regarding "con", I used it before.

Comment: That makes no sense. Are you sure its not a copy and paste error? Again, con is the SqlConnection you have created.

Comment: My apologise, I delete every other line and only include yours. This is a mistake I should not have made. I added back "SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection ..... " and everything is working but it allows me to save duplicated data with the same ID

Comment: Ok, well that makes no sense either. With NOT EXISTS, the WHERE clause in which it is used is satisfied if no rows are returned by the subquery.

Comment: Why are you not using parameters?